# power series of a sum of functions

Tags: power-series

I would like to show that 
$S(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (-1)^n ln (1+ \frac{1}{n(1+x^2)})$
has a power series representation in the neighborhood of zero,
but I'm a bit stuck, as : 
1) I can't figure a closed form of S(x) (and I reckon there isn't any).
2) My impulse would be to using the Taylor series. 
The k+1-th derivative of $ln (1+ \frac{1}{n(1+x^2)})$
is lower in module than $(2/n)k!/|x+i\sqrt{1+1/n}|^{k+1}$,
so 
$|f^{(k+1)}(c) x^{k+1}/(k+1)!|\leq (2/n(k+1))|x/(x+i\sqrt{1+1/n})|^{k+1}$, 
but I'm not sure what to do next. 
If someone has any idea it will be greatly appreciated (p.n. : I am not a student and this is not an assignment !)
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe this can help by changing the form $$\mathrm{e}^{S(x)} = \frac{\prod_{k=1}^\infty 1 + \frac{1}{2k\left(1+x^2\right)} }{\prod_{k=1}^\infty 1 + \frac{1}{(2k+1)\left(1+x^2\right)}}$$ ?

Comment: Nice, but they're both divergent products aren't they?